# Set iFrame source to "view-source: {URL}" not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to set the src of an iframe to "view-source: {URL}" using the following:

```
var url = document.getElementById('url');
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var target = document.getElementById('target');
submit.onclick = function(){
    window.frames['target'].location.href = "view-source:" + url.value; 
};
```

But it seems to set the src of the iframe relative to my website where the iframe is. I suppose because "view-source: x" only works when implemented with "location.href"?

Is this the case?

I'm using JS by the way!

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="url"></input>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<iframe id="target" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: upload your html code (makes life easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty interesting.

There must be some kind of restriction on "view-source" URLs in windows that *already exist*, because opening a new window via `window.open` [works](http://jsfiddle.net/9F73V/), but opening an existing window (that happens to be an iframe) with the "view-source" URL [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/9F73V/1/), and opening the URL in a top level window that is already present also [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/9F73V/2/) (try the last example twice with different URLs, it will only work the first time).

`view-source` is probably best treated as browser black magic voodoo and not as a regular URI scheme.

All of this was tested in Chrome, by the way. The rules may be different for other browsers supporting "view-source."